# SQL Script Foreign Key Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I am getting the error 
"Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns, table 'StudentGrade'" when trying to execute the following SQL script

```
CREATE TABLE StudentGrade

(

    StudentID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_SG_StudentID FOREIGN KEY (StudentID)
        REFERENCES Student(StudentID),
    ClassID VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Class FOREIGN KEY (ClassID, CourseID)
        REFERENCES Class(ClassID),
    CourseID VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Course FOREIGN KEY (CourseID)
        REFERENCES Course(CourseID),
    FacultyID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Faculty FOREIGN KEY (FacultyID)
        REFERENCES Faculty(FacultyID),
    Grade NUMERIC NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StudentID PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, ClassID, CourseID, FacultyID)

)
```

I know that there is something I am doing wrong with the foreign keys though I can't find anywhere where it explains how to use foreign keys and composite keys together.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your second foreign key from

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Class FOREIGN KEY (ClassID, CourseID)
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Class FOREIGN KEY (ClassID)
```

In `FK_Class` you are referencing the columns `StudentGrade.ClassID` and `StudentGrade.CourseID` into a single one `Class.ClassID` and this cannot work.

Your `FK_Course` already refers `CourseID`, so you can simply delete `CourseID` from `FK_Class` as I said above.

**Edit**

Add `CourseID` to your definition of `FK_Class` as

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Class FOREIGN KEY (ClassID, CourseID)
        REFERENCES Class(ClassID, CourseID)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Unfortunately that just give me another error
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Class' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Class'.
Maybe it would help if I showed my code for the Class table.
CREATE TABLE Class
(
 ClassID VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT PK_ClassID PRIMARY KEY (ClassID, CourseID),
 CourseID VARCHAR (64) NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT FK_CourseID FOREIGN KEY (CourseID)
   REFERENCES Course(CourseID),
 StartDate Date NULL,
 EndDate Date NULL,
 Location VARCHAR (64) NULL,
)